# How to rename multiple files in vscode (visual studio code)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wonder, if there is way to rename multiple files in visual studio code? I have tried to use find and replace, no luck.

Comment: Rename multiple files - do one by one? Find & Replace works for the inner content!

Comment: There is a vscode extension called [multiple file renamer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kmui2.multiple-files-renamer) It's not very popular, so I go for the native batch renaming though (on mac, in my case)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are a few Visual Studio Extensions that try to provide this functionality.
The first two I tried did not appear to work. There is an extension called Batch Rename which worked for me: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JannisX11.batch-rename-extension.

Here is how the extension works.

1. You highlight the files in the explorer, right-click, and select Batch Rename
2. The extension creates a text file with the names of the files you want to rename, one each line. Update the text file with the new names
3. Save the temporary text file from step 2 and the extension performs the rename.

Comment: The process is bit different now, but same effect. Note that it affects only selected files so if you want to change files inside a folder you have to expand this folder and select its files.

Comment: @harleybl When I right-click, there is no such context menu option...

Comment: @CatarinaRuna - It looks like I put the wrong URL to the plugin. The plugin that I have installed is here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JannisX11.batch-rename-extension. I updated the answer with the right URL.

Comment: @CatarinaRuna I had a similar problem, the extension only works on files and not folders.

Answer (score 79):

Here is how you can do it on Mac. `Right-click` (or `ctrl+click` or click with two fingers simultaneously on the trackpad if you are using a MacBook) on the folder that contains the files that you want to have renamed. Then click `Reveal In Finder`. Then from within finder select all files you want to rename, `right-click` the selected files and choose `Rename X items...`. Then you will see something like this:

[image]

Insert the string you want to find and the string with which you want to replace that found string and hit rename. Done

Comment: To add to this, if you want to rename multiple items across multiple directories, you can search for a pattern using Finder's searchbox, select all the results and click "Rename X items...".

Comment: IMO this is not an answer of the question. What with users of other Operating Systems?

Comment: Wojciech is right, would be great to have an answer that includes the 99% of the people that are working on work oriented OS' like Linux or Windows.

Comment: downvoted for mac. downvoted for not answering the question

Answer (score 18):

VS Code only supports single file name. On Windows, to do batch rename, you can use one of the following

```
[CMD]

// Change the extensions of all .doc files to .txt
ren *.doc *.txt

// Replace the first three characters of all files starting with 'abc' by 'xyz'
ren abc* xyz*


[PowerShell]
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('.txt','.log') }
```

**A comprehensive tutorial can be found [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-multiple-files-bulk-windows-10)**

Answer (score 6):

```
brew install rename
rename s/foo/bar/g **/*
```

Comment: This is by far the most elegant answer, provided OP understands `sed` patterns.

Answer (score 2):

#### Not an option for Visual Studio Code (yet)...

...but in **Sublime Text** with the [dired package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/dired) you can enter **rename** mode with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
This gives you a buffer with each file on its line:

```
D:\path\to\myfolder

first.file
second.file
third.file
...
umpteenth.file

 Rename files by editing them directly, then:
 Ctrl+Enter = apply changes
 Ctrl+Escape = discard changes
```

While in rename mode you can use the full power of the text editor: edit all filenames at once with multiple cursors, transpose strings (to accomplish switch renames in one fell swoop), find and replace, the [Text Pastry package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Text%20Pastry) can give you number ranges etc.

[vscode-dired](https://github.com/shirou/vscode-dired) will **not** let you do this, renames are one by one.

Answer (score 2):

VS Code has no such type of facility yet or extension on it. But using vs code terminal as a cmd and run this command on the folder where you want to change all file names from one to another like I want to change my all view files from HTML to PHP.

```
rename *.html *.php
```

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered a handy tool called [Batch Rename](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JannisX11.batch-rename-extension). It's great for renaming files. However, if you're dealing with a large number of files and need to do it recursively, my favorite approach is the following:

You can use the `find` command along with `rename` in the terminal to achieve this. Here's a step-by-step guide:

In this case I want to rename all **.js** files to **.jsx**

1. **Open a Terminal**:

   You can do this by searching for "Terminal" in the applications menu or by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + T`.
2. **Navigate to the main folder (Folder A)**:

   Use the `cd` command to change the directory. For example, if your folder A is in the home directory, you can navigate to it like this:

   ```bash
   cd ~/A
   ```
3. **Run the `find` command to locate all `.js` files**:

   Use the following command:

   ```bash
   find . -type f -name "*.js"
   ```

   This will list all `.js` files recursively in the current directory and its subdirectories.
4. **Rename the files using `rename`**:

   ```bash
      find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.js}.jsx"' {} \;
   ```

   Explanation of the command:

   - `find . -type f -name "*.js"`: Finds all files (not directories) with
     the extension `.js`.
   - `-exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.js}.jsx"' {} \;`:
   - `sh -c '...'` tells the shell to execute the following command.
   - `mv "$0" "${0%.js}.jsx"`: This renames the file from `.js` to `.jsx`.
   - `$0` refers to the file name found by `find`.
   - `"${0%.js}.jsx"` uses parameter expansion to replace the `.js` extension with `.jsx`.
5. **Verify the changes**:

   You can use `ls` to list the files in the directories and verify that they have been renamed.

***Remember to backup your data before running any commands that modify files, just to be safe.***

Comment: I use this, but it won't update references like you'd get if you did one file at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Powertoys have PowerRename utility which works nice for renaming multiple files in windows [image: PowerRename]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename

Answer (score 0):

You can not rename several files at the same time  in vscode,.
The simplest way I found is using the free "everything" utility, it takes seconds to rename a bunch of files in one or several folders.

1. Open "everything" and filter the file list.
2. Select the files you want to change
3. pick "Change Name" with rButtom
4. Popup will display with old list, the new list, the old names and the new names, if you change the new name, the new list will change accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps the easiest more detailed way is by using VSCode **Terminal** tab (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>) and selecting from the dropdown menu the **Powershell** option:

[image: Terminal/shell options]

Based on [Kin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56328390/6225838) and the [resource Kin provided (2nd page)](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-multiple-files-bulk-windows-10#rename-files-using-powershell), in order to look into the **current and all sub-folders**, these are some useful renaming possibilities:

#### Extensions rename

```
ls -R *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {[io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "log")}
```

Selects **txt** files and renames their extensions to **log**.

#### Name+extension rename

```
Get-ChildItem -R *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.Replace('.txt','-text.log')}
```

Selects **txt** files and renames them to *[ORIGINAL_NAME]***-text.log**.

#### NEW_NAME+NUMBER+extension rename (original names are discarded)

```
Get-ChildItem -R *.txt | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("NEW_NAME-{0}.log" -f $nr++)}
```

Selects **txt** files and renames them to *[NEW_NAME]***-NUMBER.log**.

How it works:

- **ls**, an alias of the **Get-ChildItem** command (equivalent in Powershell), lists current directory files;
- `-R` option allows the **recursive lookup** to happen;
- listing result is piped into a multiple **Rename-Item** commands invocation.

Answer (score -4):

You can rename a statement "in all files" highlighting it and then pressing "CTRL+R" and "CTRL+R"(again). That will replace the selected word/statement in the entire file and (if you don't disable the tooltip checkbox) in all other files where it matches.
I'm not sure if this answer your question, because this is for the text inside the files, not for the filenames.

Answer (score -4):

Renaming multiple files with a single shot is also called *batch renaming*.
This can't be done from within Visual Studio Code.

There are two ways to get what you want:

**(A) Rename files one by one**

1. Go to the Explorer view in VS Code's Side Bar.
2. Select a file you want to rename.
3. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> or choose *Rename* from that file's context menu.
4. Continue with step 2 as long as there are files you want to process.

**(B) Batch rename multiple files using other tools**

1. Go to the Explorer view in VS Code's Side Bar.
2. Select a file you want to rename.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or choose *Open Containing Folder* from that file's context menu.
4. This brings up the file explorer of your operating system.
5. Batch rename the files from there. How this is done in detail is beyond the scope of this answer (most of the time, it is just selecting all files to process and starting the rename-tool).

Comment: i think it does fit the scope of the answer

Comment: I don't have a Rename option when I right click a file in Explorer view. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAhAA.png))

Comment: To open containing folder is ALT+SHIFT+R not CTRL